# In gVim, can't generate controller appropriately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

I'm a Windows user. When I try `:Rgenerate controller Blog`, gVim giving me this message:

`:!ruby bin/rails generate controller Blog >C:\Users\ERGASH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VIe2 a31.tmp 2>&1 shell returned 1`

and doing NOTHING! What should I do next?

Comment: Did you tried this command `ruby bin/rails generate controller Blog ` manually in comma d prompt?

Comment: It is working in command prompt, but as I mentioned I am using gVim as my text editor and within the gVim I can't use rails-vim plugin's commands...

Comment: Only if you have installed the related plugin, it will work. Can you give more information on this as well as screenshots?

Comment: Here is the link: http://prntscr.com/bf35r0

Comment: Please follow these.http://askubuntu.com/questions/489210/unable-to-run-shell-script-inside-vi-vim

Comment: Windows-style recommendations are needed. I am Windows user :))))))

Answer (score 1):

The author of the plugin Tim Pope helped me with this headache. If I use `:Rgenerate` it is not working, if I use instead `:Rails generate` it is working properly. What is the problem I don't know exactly, but it is working now. Thanx "tpope"! [Here is the link from github repo](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/issues/460#issuecomment-225396005)